# make a javascript alert jump/appear on top of what a user is doing | Javascript Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, alert

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for a few days. I made a simple timer app in electron (Javascript), but I want to let the user know that the time is up by getting an alert to appear on top of what the user is doing. (just a flashing window in the taskbar could be easily overlooked)
Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

Edit:
My point was if the timer that I have already made reaches 0m, I ideally want an alert window/box to just pop up on top of whatever the user is doing. It may be Youtube, some app, or the desktop. [example (click)](https://gyazo.com/534b54b3043d724bbda87e4fea2ded90). In the example, the window has appeared on top of the background.

Thanks

AirFusion

Answer (score 1):

Create a new [BrowserWindow](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) set to be always on top, then remove the always on top flag once it has their "attention". Not removing the flag could be annoying to the user as it could remain stuck over their other work.

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, alwaysOnTop: true})

win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null
})

// Load a local HTML file
win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/my_notification.html`)

// Remove always on top flag
win.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting a constructor error `mainWindow.html:79 Uncaught TypeError: BrowserWindow is not a constructor
    at startTimer (mainWindow.html:79)`
Just to let you know, I am doing this in a html document, in <script>
Here is just part of the code (up to when I finish my timer: https://hastebin.com/teqococasa.js
The window code is at `else if (m == 0 && s ==0) `
Thx

Comment: You should do this within the electron process code, not a renderer process. If you must do it within a renderer process you need to re-include electron and other dependencies